# jframe how to get error on string data

Tags: java, swing, jframe

i am new to java this was my first class of jframe and my assignment is to take error when someone inputs a string value or character with some information so i can understand the code rather than copy pasting but now I have to create an exception that shows a user friendly message when the user enters a string instead of an integer value.
This is the code I have now with a JFrame and everything:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class MyOwn extends JFrame{
    JLabel l1, l2, l3, l4;
    JTextField t1, t2;
    JButton b1;
    public MyOwn(){}
    public MyOwn(String s){
        super(s);
    }
    public void setComponents(){
        l1=new JLabel("Addition of Two Numbers");
        l2=new JLabel("Enter First Number");
        l3=new JLabel("Enter Second Numbers");
                l4=new JLabel();
        t1=new JTextField();
        t2=new JTextField();
        b1=new JButton("Add Value");
        setLayout(null);
        l1.setBounds(100,50,200,20);
        l2.setBounds(100,80,150,20);
        t1.setBounds(250,80,200,20);
        l3.setBounds(100,100,150,20);
        t2.setBounds(250,100,200,20);
        b1.setBounds(80,180,100,20);
        l4.setBounds(50,200,200,20);
        b1.addActionListener(new Handler());
        add(l1);
        add(l2);
        add(l3);
        add(l4);
        add(t1);
        add(t2);
        add(b1);
    }
    class Handler implements ActionListener{
            @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            int a = Integer.parseInt(t1.getText());
            int b = Integer.parseInt(t2.getText());
            int r = a+b;
            l4.setText("Answer"+r);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        MyOwn MyJf=new MyOwn("text frame");
        MyJf.setComponents();
        MyJf.setSize(500,500);
        MyJf.setVisible(true);
        MyJf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

Comment: this is the kind of stuff you should know how to do before even considering working on UI 's. what have you tried so far?

Comment: Actually my teacher will tell after my research he wants everyone to try what they can do after that he will give us lecture on exceptions

Comment: And your research boils down to telling other people "please do the heavy lifting for me"? What exactly do you expect to learn from that?

Comment: You see: there are zillions and zillions of resources out that explain you how to exactly do that: check some string if it is a number using try/catch. You expect us to explain something to you that is super basic, and that you could figure out yourself by sitting down for 30 to 60 minutes and doing that **research** thing your teacher wants **you** to do.

Comment: i am researching for hours dont worry about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to show an error message on exception. Something like this:

```
class Handler implements ActionListener{
        @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        try {
            int a = Integer.parseInt(t1.getText());
            int b = Integer.parseInt(t2.getText());
            int r = a+b;
            l4.setText("Answer"+r);
        } catch (Exception e) {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(MyOwn.this, "You've entered a wrong number", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
}
```